# EnergyMicro and EZradio Pro (Si4463)

Tags: embedded, real-time, radio-transmission

I cannot find the solution for my problem.
If somebody has worked with Si4463 radio module?
According to the datasheet, it must be simple, but I cannot make it work consistently.

My transceiver sends data once each second.
1 byte preamble + 2 bytes sync + 7 bytes data + 2 bytes CRC

The receiving flow is:

1. Sending StartRX command.
2. Sending command to the Radio Module to get interrupts.
3. If Receive Interrupt Pending bit is set, I'm reading the RX fifo buffer.
4. I'm sending command to clear the RX fifo buffer
5. Sending StartRX command.

The problem is that not all packets were received.

What could be the problem?
I'm using the project that Silicon Labs Wireless Development Suite has generated.

If somebody has experience with this module - please help!!!
I will provide all needed data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help (sarcasm) :))

The answer is:
 1. Check nIRQ pin of the radio module for the interrupt
 2. When nIRQ pin goes down, read the interrupts from the radio module (don't check for CTS answer).
 3. If you get Packet Receive Interrupt Pending flag - read the rx fifo.

Thats all!!
If somebody need help with the Si4463 module - please write to me, I can help! :)